# Recurrence for a random walk question

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Let $X_i$'s be iid and define $X_1+\ldots+X_n=S_n$. I was trying to show that if $S_n$ is recurrent, then $S_{2n}$ is also recurrent. Assume these walks are in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Using Chung-Fuchs theorem, this boils down to showing that

$$\int_{(-\delta,\delta)^d} \textrm{Re}\frac{dx}{1-\phi(x)} = \infty$$ implies

$$\int_{(-\delta,\delta)^d} \textrm{Re}\frac{dx}{1-\phi^2(x)} = \infty$$

for some $\delta > 0$. It's here that I'm stuck. Does anyone have an idea how to go from here? By the way, $\phi$ denotes the characteristic function for a single increment $X_i$.

Also someone told me that $S_{kn}$ will be recurrent for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ but I figure I could show it for $S_{2n}$ first.

Comment: My hunch is to use the fact that $\phi(x)$ must be close to $1$ a lot of the time for the first integral to be divergent; then write $$\frac1{1-\phi^2(x)} = \frac1{1-\phi(x)} \frac1{1+\phi(x)} \approx \frac1{1-\phi(x)} \frac12.$$ This would work for $S_{kn}$ as well.

Comment: Wow thanks! I kept trying to use complex analysis without realizing this...